# Avoid multi fired event google tag manager - Next.js

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, next.js

I have an issue related to the way the Next.js framework works. (but this is similar to any react app with dynamic content loading)

When the GTM script loads, it binds events to DOM elements.

The GTM script is supposed to work once, and is not friendly with dynamic DOM loading since it'll not bind events to newly added DOM elements.

For instance, if you navigate from page A to page B, you keep events for the common elements (header, footer, etc.) but the main content is changed and no GTM event is bound to those.

In order to prevent that, I hacked GTM and made it believe that it had not been initialised yet. So, at each client-side navigation, it binds all events again.

```
Router.onRouteChangeComplete = () => {
  if (isBrowser() && typeof window.gtag !== undefined) {
    ga_pageview();

    // XXX Destroy all data of GTM, which will make it refresh all bindings (events) the next time GTM.initialize is called
    // This is a hack to make GTM works with SPA, because otherwise events don't trigger because DOM events are removed when Next.js load dynamic parts of the DOM
    delete window.google_tag_manager;
  }
};
```

Because of this hack, I get my events firing.
But, now GTM binds those events to the part which haven't changed **multiple times**, and end up firing 3 identical events for the same click.

I've tried to figure out ways to prevent it but I don't see any good nor simple solution.

Comment: The GTM script binds events to the document, not individual elements, and catches them via event bubbling and inspecting  the event target. Because of that it is supposed to work with newly created elements. If it doesn't, something else is wrong (e.g. something prevents events from bubbling up).

Comment: Interesting, I'll look into that, thanks for the feedback

Comment: If I do `getEventListeners(document).click.forEach(listener=>console.log(listener))` in Chrome console on a site where gtm is initialised I can indeed see that a function named 'e' is bound as a 'click' event listener. On the site that I'm looking at the gtm listener is the '1st' in the Array of click listeners. So I can remove it by `document.removeEventListener('click',getEventListeners(document).click[1].listener,false);` Theoretically you'd be able to remove the excess listeners following something similar. However... it appears that `getEventListeners` is a Chrome only utility function.

Comment: Interesting related discussion here: https://github.com/whatwg/dom/issues/412

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is utilize either the built-in history triggers in GTM and push history changes from your SPA OR utilize the data layer in GTM and push "virtual pageview" events to the datalayer to track these "pageviews" If you need more guidance, I'd be happy to provide screenshots.

Comment: If you have a link to documentation or tutorial it would indeed be most appreciated. My issue is only with events. PageViews are working fine using virtual pageviews already :) Events are basically used to track the click on a button, that doesn't necessarily generates a navigation. It's basically event tracking, not page views.